# Table naming in Latex

Tags: tables

I was trying to add table name to the table examples I borrowed from a latex wiki site. I have tried some other examples I found on this site but none of them seem to work for me. I'm new at using latex so I have no idea where I did wrong.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l |}
\hline
Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.
However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
throughout the evening. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}'
```

I just want to add title to this table.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! By "title", do you mean a caption? If so, should the caption be numbered or unnumbered?

Comment: that's what I meant. Thank you for your comment :). The question is already answered. Thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tabular material you posted will almost certainly not fit inside the available space on a page. In addition to embedding the tabular material in a `table` environment and using a `\caption` directive to create a caption, you should therefore also change the column type of the fourth column from `l` to either `p` or -- better still -- `X`; `X` is a column type provided by the `tabularx` package.

If you really want to "invite" your readers to actually read and absorb the tabular material, you should also give the table a much more open "look". The second table shown below provides some suggestions for how an open look may be achieved.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,caption,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Minimally-adapted table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | l | l | X |}
\hline
Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.
However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
throughout the evening. \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}

\caption{Cleaned-up look}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lccL@{}}
\toprule
Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\
\midrule
Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.
However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ 
\addlinespace
Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
but rain reaching the far northwest. \\
\addlinespace
Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
throughout the evening. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @samcarter - Thanks. :-) I thought a before-and-after comparison might be good way to illustrate what it means to give a table a more open "look".

Comment: I like this phrase about an open look very much - it is good description of why the `booktabs` layout looks better.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to give the table a title but not a "Table <n>" prefix, simply write `\caption*{...}` instead of `\caption{...}`.

Comment: IMO the biggest improvement here comes from `\raggedright` rather than the "open look" (although the latter is also an improvement).

Comment: @EspeciallyLime - Thanks for this. Just to add a nuance to your comment: Without the elimination of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines, i.e., without giving the table a more open look, I believe that it would look quite odd to switch off justification in the cells. (Those vertical lines practically *demand* full justification of the material in the cells!) Put differently, once a more open look is achieved, further improvements -- such as those achieved by `\raggedright` or, here, `\RaggedRight` -- become feasible. :-)

Comment: @Mico Yes, that's a good point, I just tried `\RaggedRight` with the vertical lines and it does look a bit strange :)

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but are you looking for a `\caption` for your table? If yes then you should use a `table` environment instead of `center`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{text}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l |}
\hline
Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.
However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
throughout the evening. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However I would suggest a slightly different layout for the table (please see [@Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417258/36296) for an explanation why this kind of layout should be prefered)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{text}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lllX@{}}
\toprule
Day & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Temperature} & Summary\\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(rl){2-3}  \cmidrule(l){4-4}
& min. & max. & \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-2}  \cmidrule(rl){3-3} 
Monday & \SI{11}{\degreeCelsius} & \SI{22}{\degreeCelsius} & A clear day with lots of sunshine.
However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures.\\ \addlinespace
Tuesday & \SI{9}{\degreeCelsius} & \SI{19}{\degreeCelsius} & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
but rain reaching the far northwest.\\ \addlinespace
Wednesday & \SI{10}{\degreeCelsius} & \SI{21}{\degreeCelsius} & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
throughout the evening.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]